# Mootools onClick send object

Tags: javascript, mootools

I m trying to send an object to another out of the object it self.

```
var Tile = new Class({
    initialize : function(){
        this.inner = new Element(...);
        this.inner.addEvent('click', function() {
            popup.open(this);
        });
    }
});
```

If I m alerting any membervariable from Tile out op Popup it's alerting 'undefined'.
What am I doing wrong?

```
var Popup = new Class({
    initialize : function(){
    },
    open : function(tile) {
        alert(tile.width);
    }
});
```

Kind regards!

Comment: Please include the code where `popup` is instantiated.

Comment: Popup is instanciated on window.addEvent('domready'...) BEFORE Tile. I updated the first post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `this` to the `popup` object, you are passing the element itself (which I believe is your intention). However, elements don't by default have a property called `width`.

Perhaps you are looking for `getSize();`? This returns a two-property object (`x` and `y`), corresponding respectively to the width and height of the element.

I've approximated your code into the following jsFiddle, give it a try: http://jsfiddle.net/g4SmJ/

For reference, here is the new `Popup` class code:

```
var Popup = new Class({
    initialize : function(){
    },
    open : function(tile) {
        size = tile.getSize();
        console.log(size);    // console.log provides a nicer interface for debugging, you can pass objects into it! Use the Chrome Inspector or Firebug to see its output.
        alert(size.x);
    }
});
```

---

In response to your comment:

> Oh ups I did not meant to alert the doms width, sorry for that. What I posted is smaller code from the full object. Width actually was a defined member in Tiles that I wanted to alert out of Popup

In this case, then when you are sending the call to `.open();`, you passed `this` into the function call, but *you are not passing the `Tile` object*! Instead, you passed the `inner` element you created.

Rewrite `Tile` thusly:

```
var Tile = new Class({
    initialize : function(){
        var self = this;
        this.inner = new Element(...);
        this.inner.addEvent('click', function() {
            popup.open(self);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh ups I did not meant to alert the doms width, sorry for that. What I posted is smaller code from the full object. Width actually was a defined member in Tiles that I wanted to alert out of Popup

Comment: Please see the revised post. :) Both solutions provided by @Adidi and myself should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking to send the `Tile` instance. 
Like the above answer - when you send `this` inside `addEvent` method you are sending the element itself that called the event: in your case you are sending instance of inner since you define the onclick on it.

If you want to send the tile instance you have 2 options:

1) bind to to the function this - meaning "connect" the current scope you are in(Tile) into the event:

```
var Tile = new Class({
    initialize : function(){
        this.inner = new Element(...);
        this.inner.addEvent('click', function() {
            popup.open(this); // <- now this is 'Tile' instance 
        }.bind(this)); //bind this to click
    }
});
```

2) Save the instance outside the scope of the function and use it inside:

```
var Tile = new Class({
    initialize : function(){
        this.inner = new Element(...);
        var self = this; //save the this to var 'self'
        this.inner.addEvent('click', function() {
            popup.open(self); //use self which holds the Tile instance
        });
    }
});
```